# Laravel - What's the right relationship?

Tags: laravel

- I have `users` table. (User Model & Controller)
- each `user` can start a `fight`. the `fight` table contains the user_id. (I already have Fight Model & Controller)
- Once the `fight` has finished, the record is deleted from the `fight` table.

**The question:**

1. What's the right relationship between `users` and `fight` so I can access the user fight within user->fight?
2. How I can check using Laravel to make sure the user has no fight in the `fight` table before allowing him to create a new one? `(SELECT * FROM fight WHERE user_id = USER_ID)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct relationship on the user side is:

```
$this->hasMany(Flight::class);
```

Also about your second question, there is an 'has' method that can query a relationship for existance.
So in your case:

```
$user->has('flight');
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations